# Trying to use listFiles() function, but array of files is empty, Java, Andriod Studio

Tags: java, android

The debugger tells me that it's impossible to find a null array length. What can be wrong? In the `three` folder there are 2 `.mp3` files.

```
File dir = new File("C://Android Projects//app//src//main//res//three");
File[] listOfFiles = dir.listFiles();
int itemIndex = (int)(Math.random()*listOfFiles.length);
```

Comment: Uh you are trying to access it from your computer which is not present on your phone

Comment: `listFiles` returns null if it can't access the folder (e.g. it doesn't exist).

Comment: @khelwood they hardcoded their project dir, which is not visible when compiled into phone or virtual machine. They should use the folder `raw` but I am unaware why they are using `listFiles()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always place your media files inside `raw` or `assets` dir of android.

I will be giving an example of `assets` Create a folder called `asset` in your app level directory and place this code

```
String[] listOfFiles = getContext().getResources().getAssets().list("");
int itemIndex = (int)(Math.random()*listOfFiles.length);
```

For reference take a look at [this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager#list%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Btw, same happens, when i try to apply this function for `raw` folder

Comment: How are you doing it? You can't put a direct path to your project to raw folder. Because its never there when its compiled

Comment: i got it now, ty a lot, the main issue is that im studying java without theory, practically, so today i've learned something new